# Retrieve the last line in one to one relation with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, yii

Something rare to happen is one to one where the second table can have millions of results for the first one. For example, I have a 'radcliente' table that has millions of 'radacct', but need to filter only with the last acct. The following are examples for better explanation:

This is criteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = [
    'acct', // slow because it will take millions of lines to have only the last
];
$criteria->together = true;
$clientes = Cliente::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

This is generated query by Yii (very slow, more then 40 seconds, it return millions of rows to use only one in AR):

```sql
SELECT
  `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,
  -- ...
  `t`.`spc_serasa` AS `t0_c56`,
  `acct`.`radacctid` AS `t1_c0`,
  -- ...
  `acct`.`cliente_id` AS `t1_c27`
FROM
  `radcliente` `t`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `acct` ON (`acct`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
ORDER BY
  radacctid DESC
```

After apply my solution limit join to one row (is this fast! 200ms-):

```sql
SELECT
  `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,
  ..
  `t`.`spc_serasa` AS `t0_c56`,
  `acct`.`radacctid` AS `t1_c0`,
  -- ...
  `acct`.`cliente_id` AS `t1_c27`
FROM
  `radcliente` `t`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `acct` ON (
    acct.radacctid = (
      SELECT   radacctid
      FROM     `radacct` `acct`
      WHERE    (acct.cliente_id = t.id)
      ORDER BY radacctid DESC
      LIMIT 1
    )
  )
```

This is the generated query by CActiveDataProvider to total item count with my solution of limit join to one (slow, 10 seconds to count):

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,
    -- ...
    `t`.`spc_serasa` AS `t0_c56`,
    `endereco_instalacao`.`id` AS `t1_c0`,
    `telefones`.`id` AS `t2_c0`,
    `telefones`.`telefone` AS `t2_c3`,
    `emails`.`id` AS `t3_c0`,
    `emails`.`email` AS `t3_c3`,
    `metodo_cobranca`.`id` AS `t4_c0`,
    `acct`.`radacctid` AS `t5_c0`,
    `acct`.`framedipaddress` AS `t5_c22`
  FROM
    `radcliente` `t`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao` ON ( 
      endereco_instalacao.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao`
        WHERE (
          endereco_instalacao.cliente_id = t.id
        )
        LIMIT 1
      )
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_telefone` `telefones` ON (`telefones`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_email` `emails` ON (`emails`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca` ON (
      metodo_cobranca.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM   `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca`
        WHERE  (metodo_cobranca.cliente_id = t.id)
               AND (metodo_cobranca.arquivo = 'nao')
        ORDER BY metodo_cobranca.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
      )
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `acct` ON (
      acct.radacctid = (
        SELECT   radacctid
        FROM     `radacct` `acct`
        WHERE    (acct.cliente_id = t.id)
        ORDER BY radacctid DESC
        LIMIT 1
     )
  )
  GROUP BY t.id
) sq
```

But the problem is in the count generated by CActiveDataProvider (about 10 seconds to return the result) would have a way to optimize without having to lose the relationship (because I need to filter by a relationship in the future)?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your response. I've been doing some tests and noticed that is slow in all cases, the table 'radacct' exacerbates the problem by its size, which should not therefore limit the 1 in the subquery. Follow the models and the link to access the system, if you need to authenticate is:

To access:

http://177.86.111.30/dev2/teste

username: help

password: 1

To download models and schema of radcliente and radacct: http://177.86.111.30/files.zip

Comment: Please line out what indexes are defined on the tables in questions.

Comment: 1. Consider reducing the problem to the minimum required to prove the concept. 2. Then provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle). 3. Then provide a desired result set, corresponding with the dataset provided in 2.

Comment: The problem is related to the millions of rows in the table 'radacct' it is impossible to put on SQLFiddle, I will open my server and pass a link in the page for testing. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you need to skip Active Record and use other Yii DB API to process your query http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32502-120-million-rows-iterator-needed/

Comment: The records are loaded only 10, this count is to count the total to be used in CGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ON id = ( SELECT ... LIMIT 1 )` try adding another JOIN (not LEFT JOIN):

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... LIMIT 1 ) x ON ...
```

The fear I have with your code is that it will be evaluating that subquery repeatedly, whenever it needs to check the ON clause.  My rewrite will cause the subquery to happen only once.

Your query looks like a "correlated" subquery, so you would need to rephrase it to be non-correlated, if possible.

Comment: I tried that too. I tried to put the COUNT directly, but there was no problem with GROUP BY, remove GROUP BY does not count correctly.